# PageSpeed Insights error by setting H1 to inline

Tags: error-handling, pagespeed

I get an error when I test my site speed with PageSpeed Insights. My Code is 100% clean. The error message is:

> Lighthouse returned error: INTERNAL: APP::1: Abnormal renderer termination, status = crashed exit_code = 1

There is no problem when I don't set `H1` to inline, but I need to set that for layout reasons.

The problem appears on [this site](https://www.pixelfutter.de).
Is this a SEO problem or can I ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing your console error messages, occasionally these can break the headless browser that audits your site. You can always test the site by going to settings > more tools > developer tools > audits. (or press F12 to open developer tools) ** Google Chrome